# Cómo cerrar snackBar de materialUI al cambiar de componente?

Tags: angular, material

Estoy con un problema con snackBar, es uno simple como se puede encontrar en la documentación de Material,
pero solo encontré 2 formas de cerrarlo: temporizador y .dismiss().
El problema viene cuando no se cierra y cambio de componente, este sigue mostrándose en la pantalla,
cómo puedo hacer que se cierre al cambiar de url o componente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es (en lugar de abrir el snackbar desde el componente) crear un servicio que se encargue de esa tarea.
De esa manera no importa en que lugar de la app estés, siempre tendrás acceso  la referencia del SnackBar

El código sería algo así:

```js
@Injectable()
export class SnackBarService {
   constructor(private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}
   
   openSnackBar(message, action) {
      this.snackBarRef = this._snackBar.open(message, action, {
         duration: 2000,
      });
   }

   closeSnackBar() {
      if (this.snackBarRef) this.snackBarRef.dismiss(); //Revisar primero si la referencia existe
      this.snackBarRef = null;
   }
}
```

Y este servicio lo podes utilizar en cualquier componente o modulo.
Incluso podes adjuntar un listener al router de Angular para cerrar snackbars cada que cambiés de ruta.